# Array showing all values of loop instead of specific value to post

Tags: widgets, dashboard

I am trying to make a plugin that allows a user to add custom dashboard widgets that feature individual feeds. I am using Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Type UI plugins. The user puts in the feed name (feed_name) and the URL of the feed (feed_url) When I run my code, the user can create as many dashboard widgets as they want, but all of the feeds are returning in all of the widgets (the feed_name is working correctly) So what I hope to achieve is each widget has only the feed from the corresponding feed_url.

```
 /** START The News Feed Dashboard Widget */

add_action( 'wp_dashboard_setup', 'dfdw_feed_dashboard_add_widgets' );


function dfdw_feed_dashboard_add_widgets(){

  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'dashboard_feed',
                  'numberposts' => '-1'
                );

  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      the_ID();
  

 $feed_name = get_field('feed_name' );

    wp_add_dashboard_widget( $feed_name, __( $feed_name ), 'my_cool_widget' );

  endwhile;
 
  }


  function my_cool_widget() {

    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'dashboard_feed',
    'numberposts' => '-1'
  );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

      
  
 $feed_url = get_field('feed_url' );  

  $feed = array(
        array(
            'url'          => $feed_url,
            'items'        =>1,
            'show_summary' => 1,
            'show_author'  => 0,
            'show_date'    => 1,
          

        ),

    );
  
   
  ob_start(); // start output buffering
    wp_dashboard_primary_output( $feed_name, $feed );
    $buffer = ob_get_clean(); // get the buffer without printing the content

    // add the target attribute to the a-tag:
    $result = str_replace("<a class='rsswidget'",
                          "<a class='rsswidget' target='_blank'", $buffer);
    echo $result;
 
  endwhile;
};
```

Comment: Why are you buffering the output?

Comment: It is a workaround to open the feed in a new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
/** START The News Feed Dashboard Widget */

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'dfdw_feed_dashboard_add_widgets');

function dfdw_feed_dashboard_add_widgets()
{

    $args = array('post_type' => 'dashboard_feed',
        'numberposts' => '-1',
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
        $feed_id = get_post()->ID;

        $feed_name = get_field('feed_name');

        wp_add_dashboard_widget($feed_name, $feed_name, 'my_cool_widget', null, $feed_id);

    endwhile;

}

function my_cool_widget($post, $callback_args)
{
  $post_id = $callback_args['args'];
  $feed_url = get_field('feed_url', $post_id);
  $feed_name = get_field('feed_name', $post_id);

  $feed = array(
      array(
          'url' => $feed_url,
          'items' => 5,
          'show_summary' => 1,
          'show_author' => 0,
          'show_date' => 1,

      ),

  );
  ob_start(); // start output buffering
  wp_dashboard_primary_output($feed_name, $feed);
  $buffer = ob_get_clean(); // get the buffer without printing the content

  // add the target attribute to the a-tag:
  $result = str_replace("<a class='rsswidget'",
      "<a class='rsswidget' target='_blank'", $buffer);
  echo $result;
}
```